# how to add deterministic vector operations in PYMC3?

Tags: python, numpy, theano, pymc, pymc3

how can deterministic vector operations be implemented in PYMC3? for example the model:

```
M ~ Unif(-5, 5)
S ~ Unif(0, |1 / M|)
data ~ Normal(M, S)
```

M is mean of Gaussian observations and S is standard deviation. The standard deviation is assumed to be uniformly distributed in [0, |1/M|] (abs value necessary when M is negative).

this code:

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
size = 20
with pm.Model() as model:
    # M ~ Unif(-5, 5)
    M = pm.Uniform("M", -5., 5., shape=size)
    # S ~ Unif(0, |1 / M|)
    # how to divide by vector and take abs val?
    S = pm.Uniform("S", np.zeros(size), abs(1. / M), shape=size)
    data = pm.Normal("data", M, sd=S, shape=size)
```

has the error:

```
  File "/Users/mvd/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc3/distributions/distribution.py", line 67, in get_test_val
    str(defaults) + " pass testval argument or adjust so value is finite.")
AttributeError: <pymc3.distributions.continuous.Uniform object at 0x10d1e1f10> has no finite default value to use, checked: ['median', 'mean', 'mode'] pass testval argument or adjust so value is finite.
```

do i need to use theano to achieve this operation on vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problematic part of your model is `1/M`. Because this goes to infinity as M approach to 0. In fact in your example, the first proposed value for M is 0 (the mean of the lower and upper boundaries) hence the error of "no finite value" you are getting (the error comes from the variable S).

One way to fix this is to pass a reasonable `testval` value to M (in this case anything but 0), for example:

```
M = pm.Uniform("M", -5., 5., shape=size, testval=0.1)
```

Now M will be initialized at 0.1 (instead of 0.)

As a side note, intuitively I think NUTS will have trouble to properly sample from this model, thus I think Metropolis could be a better choice here, but feel free to experiment with different samplers.

Comment: thank you. also: when can you use deterministic expressions of random variables in PYMC3 like ``abs(1. / M)`` without making custom theano functions for them? why does ``pm.Uniform("S", np.zeros(size), abs(1. / M), shape=size)`` simply work?

Comment: You are welcome. Theano understand operators like `/` and you can mix python/NumPy and theano variables in general. What you cannot do, directly, is to use theano variable for functions that are expecting python/NumPy variables. In such a case you can use the `as_op` decorator.